# exim4: how to add an address as BCC to all the outgoing emails?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, smtp, exim

I'm working on an Ubuntu 20.04 web server where **exim4** is used to send emails from the PHP application running on it.

Due to diagnostic and archival needs, I need to **configure exim4 to automatically BCC an additional address to ALL the outgoing emails**.

TO be cleared: all the original recipients of the outgoing email must remain the same. I just need to add my additional `archive@example.com` address to the list (as BCC).

My exim4 skill are near-zero (I generally use postfix), so please behave ;-).

I tried to follow along [this post](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=6298#p60287), but nothing happens. I don't have a `/etc/exim/exim.conf` (most likely due to the "split configuration" mode of exim4) so I created a new file in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/nano 95_zane` with this:

```
system_filter = /etc/exim4/exim.filter
```

Then I created `/etc/exim4/exim.filter`:

```
if first_delivery
   and ("$h_to:, $h_cc:, $h_bcc" not contains "example.com")
   and ("$h_from:" not contains "example.com")
then
   unseen deliver "archive@example.com"
endif
```

I restarted exim4 and re-tried, but nothing happens: the intended recipient gets the message, but my additional address is not BBC'ed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I just had to add `system_filter = /etc/exim4/exim.filter` directly a the top of `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` and now it works as expected.